# Spring retry, recovery method only for some cases

Tags: java, spring, spring-retry

i need to implement a recovery method that kicks in only in some specific cases. is it possible with Spring Retry? it seems i can't do it using just:

- Policy as it can't change an error into a correct result.
- RetryListener as it can't return value from onError

.

```
int do_something_that_may_throw_exception() {...}

int analyze_thrown_exception(exc) {

  switch (analyze(exc)) {
     case 1: 
       // everything is fine, don't retry, the returned result should be 7
     case 2:
       // transient error, request another retry
     default:
      // permanent exception, raise an error, don't retry
  }
}
```

Comment: You could always employ two queues; one which sends to DLQ immediately and one which retries. Case 2 in your pseudo code would requeue the message on the secondary queue.

Comment: yes, it's just i prefer to reuse existing libraries whenever possible. but i'm not sure if spring retry is designed for that case

Comment: What if you have 2 recovery methods, each of which handles a different exception? Then throw the exception for the recovery you want?

Comment: no, one error class can have different details. some of them result in 'all is fine, exit without error' state, others result in 'keep retrying' and others result in 'permanent error, exist with exception'

Answer (score 2):

The way spring-retry works is that you add the Retryable annotation to some service method, and that method gets retried up to a number of times that you specify in the annotation. If something within the method throws an exception, that exception is compared to the exception specified by the Retryable annotation, and if they are the same then the method gets re-tried. Exceptions that don't match what Retryable is looking for, and retryable exceptions thrown when the method has already been tried the set number of times both have the recover method called for them. The recover method is overloaded with the type of the exception. Recover methods can return a default value or rethrow the exception passed in, or throw a different exception.

I would make a specific exception class for retryable exceptions and wrap only those exceptions that I wanted to be retried in that. That makes it easy to make sure nothing else gets retried. For other exceptions, you can let them be thrown and they will be handled by a recover method that you write for them. Then of course you can have the method directly return a result.

You can definitely catch an exception in your code and either directly return a result, or let it be thrown, and have the recover method return a result.

Here is an example demonstrating both retryable and non-retryable exceptions:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyRetryableService {

    private final RandomNumberService randomNumberService;
  
    @Retryable(value = {RetryableException.class}, maxAttempts = 2, backoff = @Backoff(delay=100)) 
    public int doStuff(String s) {

        log.info("doing stuff with {}, try = {}", s, RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext().getRetryCount() + 1);
        int i = randomNumberService.randomNumber();

        // simulate having something bad happen that is recoverable
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            String issue = "oops";
            log.warn("condition = {}", issue);
            throw new RetryableException(issue);
        }

        // simulate having something bad happen that is not recoverable
        if (i % 5 == 0) {
            String issue = "ohnoes";
            log.warn("condition = {}", issue);
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(issue);
        }

        return i;
    }

    /*
    Provides default value and writes to log once retries are exhausted
    */
    @Recover
    public int recover(RetryableException e, String s) {

        log.info("in recover for RetryableException, s is {}", s);
        return -1;
    }

    /*
    Need to provide this so that non-recoverable exception doesn't get wrapped in an ExhaustedRetriesException
    with message that no recover method was found
    */
    @Recover
    public int recover(RuntimeException e, String s) {

        log.info("in recover for RuntimeException, s is {}", s);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

This code is part of a small working example at https://github.com/nathan-hughes/spring-retry-examples. Also I found this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry) helpful.